# I want use Expo/React Native to read a card in my payment machine using magnetic reader

Tags: react-native, expo

I am developing a mobile app in Expo/React Native for card machines with cameras and magnetic card readers (tectoy, sunmi, etc). The company has provided personal cards to be swiped through these machines, and I need to read the cards using the magnetic card reader. However, I am new to Expo, and I haven't found a library or function yet that supports this type of sensor.

How can i do this?

I found a library in Expo to use the camera and read QR codes, so I thought it would be the same for reading any information passed through the magnetic card reader. However, I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: Expo/React Native focus on UI development than low level hardware integration. Using platform native implementation is more practical - https://developer.sunmi.com/docs/en-US/xeghjk491/fxzeghjk557